# Schedule a webpage update with Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I maintain a website for a resort and need to update the activities daily. Some days activities go later than I am at work.

Is there a way to automatically publish a page in Dreamweaver at a certain time? I am currently using Dreamweaver CS 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this with Dreamweaver. You could use another FTP client, like [Core FTP](http://www.coreftp.com/) and then schedule an upload.

- http://www.coreftp.com/
- http://www.coreftp.com/docs/web1/Schedule_FTP_transfers.htm

There may be other FTP clients that can do this, too.